# Using easeljs with typescript: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EventDispatcher'

Tags: typescript, easeljs

I'm trying to use easeljs with typescript

I've setup typescript, and installed typings by:

```
$ typings install easeljs --ambient
```

I have a file named `canvas.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="browser/main.d.ts" />

var canv = < HTMLCanvasElement > document.createElement("canvas");
canv.width = 800;
canv.height = 600;
canv.style.border = "5px solid silver";

var stage = new createjs.Stage(canv);

var circle = new createjs.Shape();
circle.graphics.beginFill("DeepSkyBlue").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
circle.x = 100;
circle.y = 100;
stage.addChild(circle);

stage.update();

document.body.appendChild(canv);
```

Calling `tsc canvas.ts` I get:

```
typings/main/ambient/easeljs/easeljs.d.ts(187,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EventDispatcher'.
typings/main/ambient/easeljs/easeljs.d.ts(657,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Timeline'.
typings/main/ambient/easeljs/easeljs.d.ts(679,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Tween'.
typings/main/ambient/easeljs/easeljs.d.ts(797,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EventDispatcher'.
typings/main/ambient/easeljs/easeljs.d.ts(818,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EventDispatcher'.
```

If I do `typings install tweenjs --ambient` only the messages about `EventDispatcher` remain. Installing `createjs` using typings won't help.

After calling `tsc` the .js file seems to be generated correctly (I can see the circle), but the error seems to indicate that I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas what it is?

Disclaimer: never used javascript/typescript before so it's probably something trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typings doesn't install dependencies for *ambient* stuff by default as they can cause module dependency problems (e.g. the diamond problem).

However it does tell you which ones you might need:

[image]

You figured out `tweenj.d.ts`. You also need `createjs-lib` as pointed out